# phalcon webtools.php: not in include_path

Tags: php, phalcon

I created a project using phalcon command line

```
phalcon create-project brujobs --enable-webtools
```

When i test the webtools page i get

```
Warning: require(/home/myname/phalcon-devtools/scripts/Phalcon/Web/Tools.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vhost/dev.myname.be/htdocs/myname/public/webtools.php on line 22 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/myname/phalcon-devtools/scripts/Phalcon/Web/Tools.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/vhost/dev.myname.be/htdocs/myname/public/webtools.php on line 22
```

I suppose the issue is that phalcon is trying to include files that are not included in my php include_path directive.

```
include_path    .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php    .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php
```

Question is: what would be the proper way to fix that? Modify the whole server's php.ini file 's include_path directive just for phalcon webtools feels wrong to me.

Comment: "failed to open stream: Permission denied" isn't going to have much to do with the include_path.  Check file and directory permissions *and ownership* all the way up to the file.

Comment: Just to check, i 've set permissions and ownership on /var/www/vhost/dev.myname.be/htdocs/myname/public/webtools.php  to owner: root, perm: 0777  Still no go.

Comment: Ah, but that's not the file being complained about, it's `/home/myname/phalcon-devtools/scripts/Phalcon/Web/Tools.php`.  Also, dude, nothing PHP should ever be owned by root, it should be owned by the same user that PHP runs as, so the owner of the FastCGI host or the owner of the HTTP server depending on how it's being run.

Comment: ok, so apache in my case. thanks for the heads up.